# Java 8 Stream how to merge 2 non-equal-size lists with custom logic to pick duplicates

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have 2 lists of map objects.

```
 "list1": [
    {
      "partyId": "1",
      "accountId": "1",
      "sourceSystem": "1",
    },
    {
      "partyId": "2",
      "accountId": "2",
      "sourceSystem": "2",
    }]
```

and this is list2.

```
 "list2": [
    {
      "partyId": "3",
      "accountId": "3",
      "sourceSystem": "3",
    },
    {
      "partyId": "1",
      "accountId": "2",
      "sourceSystem": "2",
    }]
```

Now I need to merge list1 and list2 to have this output.

```
 "merged": [
    {
      "partyId": "1",
      "accountId": "1",
      "sourceSystem": "1",
    },
    {
      "partyId": "2",
      "accountId": "2",
      "sourceSystem": "2",
    },
    {
      "partyId": "3",
      "accountId": "3",
      "sourceSystem": "3",
    }]
```

so you can see it merges 1,2 and 3 from list1 and list2. Also, since list2 has one partyId=1 (also in list1) but the details(accountId and sourceSystem) are different so the partyId=1 in list1 is selected.

How can I do this with java 8 stream? Or the only way is to convert them into java objects and do for loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may do it like so in one go,

```
List<Map<String, String>> resultMap = Stream.concat(mapListOne.stream(), mapListTwo.stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> m.get("partyId"), Collectors.toList()))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getValue().get(0))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This is a two step computation where you first compute the `List` of maps for each partyId value as a map and then get the first element on each `List` to compute the final result.

Comment: I have only one question left. How do you know this "e -> e.getValue().get(0)" will return the element from list1? where is the guarantee?

Comment: Both `Stream.concat` and `List` respects the order. So if you have given listOne first, it will take it.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to iterate through the first list and collect as a Map using the `partyId` as the `key` and `Party` as `value` :

```
Map<String, CustomObject> customObjectMap = customObjectList1.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(CustomObject::getPartyId, customObject -> customObject, (a, b) -> b));
```

then iterating through the second list and filtering our existing partyIds

```
customObjectList2.stream()
        .filter(customObject -> !customObjectMap.containsKey(customObject.getPartyId()))
        .forEach(customObject -> customObjectMap.put(customObject.getPartyId(), customObject));
```

retrieving the `values` from the map as a final output

```
List<CustomObject> merged = new ArrayList<>(customObjectMap.values());
```

---

If modifying the existing collections doesn't harm your code anyhow, then you can try to get the `Set` of keys on the `partyId` from list1

```
Set<String> partyIds = customObjectList1.stream().map(CustomObject::getPartyId).collect(Collectors.toSet());  // set assuming a list wouldn't have duplicate partyId
```

then remove the objects from another list based on the existing keys

```
customObjectList2.removeIf(p -> partyIds.contains(p.getPartyId()));
```

and finally addAll into one list of objects

```
customObjectList1.addAll(customObjectList2); // customObjectList1 is now your 'merged'
```

Comment: ..and I noticed, *Or the only way is to convert them into java objects*... yes please. using `Map` for a similar type of concrete information makes less sense.

Answer (score 0):

if the logic is simply all items in the first list plus all items in the second list that don't match an item in the first list, then:

```
List<Map<String,String>> result = Stream.concat(list1.stream(),
    list2.stream().filter(m2 -> list1.stream()
        .noneMatch(m1 -> m1.get("partyId").equals(m2.get("partyId"))))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```